# JCanvas didn't work I can't draw anything

Tags: jquery

I can't draw anything, did anyone see the error? I want to try when press the button, didn't work and when the document is ready didn't work either.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src='jcanvas.min.js'></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>IO</title>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#act').click(function(){
        $('canvas').drawArc({
            fillStyle: 'black',
            x: 100, y: 100,
            radius: 50
            });
    });
    $('canvas').drawArc({
            fillStyle: 'black',
            x: 100, y: 100,
            radius: 50
            });

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<button id="act" type="button">Actualizar</button>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>
  <input type="number" name="quantity" min="-100000" max="100000">
  </p>
</p>
<canvas id='can' width='500' height='500'></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You JCanvas code is fine.

The order in which we load script files in web page matters.
JCanvas library uses jQuery.
So, loading jQuery first would solve the problem.

Also, if you are checking on local machine, you can load jQuery CDN using HTTP.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='jcanvas.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: Still dont work, I download Jquery to make sure isnt a web problem and I use `<script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Recheck if the line for loading jQuery is above the line for loading JCanvas in <head>. I tested on a local machine and it works fine. Make sure canvas is supported in your browser.